# Vim-based alternative for Emacs tramp-mode

Tags: ssh, vim, remote, emacs, r

I'm currently using `vim` (actually `neovim`) as my IDE for writing and executing `GNU R`-code (using the `Nvim-R`-plugin, see also https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R, which serves as my REPL), which works great on my local machine. When having higher workloads or demands, I'm `ssh`-ing into a remote machine, installing my `nvim` plugins and running `nvim` as a "local" application on the server.

Recently I realized that `Emacs` has the ingenious `TRAMP` mode (Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocols, see also https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode), which allows to not only open files remotely, but also execute commands on a remote machine. From what I understand this means that I could use `Emacs` as a REPL (e.g. using `ESS`), writing code using my local `Emacs`-instance, but executing it on a remote machine where I have `GNU R` installed (see also https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers).

I'd be interested to know if something similar exists for `vim` or `neovim`. I'm aware that I can edit files remotely using

```
vim scp://USER@SERVER:PORT//absolute/path/to/file
```

or

```
vim
:e scp://USER@SERVER:PORT//absolute/path/to/file
```

but from what I understand this actually creates a temporary copy of the file on my local machine; when running my `Nvim-R`-REPL this opens the working directory locally on `/tmp/something`.

I thought about experimenting with `vim-slime` (see https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime), `repl.nvim` (see https://github.com/HiPhish/repl.nvim) or `neoterm` (see https://github.com/kassio/neoterm), but I'm unsure if I could be able to try and replicate an `Emacs`-like experience.

Any ideas? Has anybody achieved something similar?

Comment: Personally I'd just run Vim in an SSH session to the remote host... If you like the Emacs features but prefer Vim modal editing, check out `evil-mode` which implements modal interface, pretty close to full Vim, in Emacs.

Comment: @filbranden: I also thought about `emacs` with `evil-mode`. To be honest, I was already thinking about swiching to `emacs`, but after more than 1K lines of `.vimrc ` or `init.vim` this step isn't taken lightly - especially since I assume it would take quite some time until I would have made made my `emacs`-configuration as tuned to my needs as it is with `vim`/`neovim` and I would reach the same level of productivity.

Comment: Yeah... Like I said, personally I'd just run Vim in an SSH session to the remote host... :-) I guess most Vimmers tend to be more comfortable in the terminal, while the text version of Emacs is crappy, that's why Emacs folks end up building something like Tramp while Vimmers just run it on the target host... You might want to consider asking this question (or asking to get it migrated) at the [vi.se] stack, someone there might have a better idea or know of an appropriate plug-in for you. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to move this to [vi.se], just delete it from here and repost there. If we migrate it, it will appear on the target site as though asked on the 27th of august, so it's much cleaner to simply repost it after deleting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I answered this question already on [`vi.SE`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27249/vim-based-alternative-for-emacs-tramp-mode) and only duplicated the answer for completeness sake.

---

I still haven't found the perfect solution, but one that works for me reasonably well: by using [`vim-slime`](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) (which is written in only `vimscript`).

In my config-file (`~/.config/nvim/init.vim` or `~/.vimrc`), I'm using the following line(s):

```
let g:slime_target = "neovim"
"let g:slime_target = "vimterminal"
"let g:slime_target = "screen"
"let g:slime_target = "tmux"
```

Only one of them is needed. The first line is used for `neovim`, but if I'm using `vim` I use the second one (uncommented). In my workflow I'm `ssh`-ing into a remote machine, then open the file I want to use (e.g. my `script.R` or `list_of_commands.sh`), then create a `:vertical split` and subsequently open a `:terminal`, where I can then run e.g. my `GNU R`-interpreter or a `bash`. If one prefers to use a terminal multiplexer, the new split can be created using either `screen` (with `Ctrl-a |` `Ctrl-a l` `Ctrl-a c`) or `tmux` (with `Ctrl-b %`) and have the appropriate line from above (uncommented) in the config-file.

When I then invoke the `:SlimeSend`-command (abbreviated with `Ctrl-c` `Ctrl-c`, so the same key-combination has to be pressed twice), the text I'm currently having my cursor on is selected to be send to the target (which, when the configuration is correct and your split is already present, is written in correctly by default).

That might not be as elegant as `TRAMP` in `Emacs`, but it works. But if anyone has ideas for improvement, don't hesitate to suggest them!